# Most ports unreachable

Tags: centos, iptables, port

I'm running CentOS on a VPS with the following iptables configuration

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Is there anything here that would render ports 25, 80, 110, 143, 993, and 995 unreachable? Telnetting to these ports from within my VPS via `telnet localhost <portnumber>` works, so I'm sure the services are running. Yet trying to telnet into them from my local computer says

```
Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Only ports 22 and 53 can be reached via my local machine.

Comment: it would be better if you posted the result of `netstat -tulpn | grep :80` and the other ports too. Also could make sure that you have restarted iptables ?

Comment: Doing a `sudo yum install netstat` says `No package netstat available`. I have restarted iptables multiple times and made sure to save the configuration beforehand.

Comment: `sudo yum install net-tools` then try the netstat command again

Comment: or try this: `ss -tulpn | grep :80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put rule `-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` after your ACCEPT rules? Looks like this rule block all ports, and iptables don't open ports even you have rules for them.